# Spring CLI cannot find main class after installing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cli

I have JDK 1.8, gradle 6.1, and apache-maven 3.6.3.

I installed the Spring CLI and have set the path variable correctly
However when I try to run even a simple command like:

spring --version

I get the following error:

> Could not find or load main class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher

I haven't made a project or antying I am just making sure it works after installing.
I'm assuming I am missing some file or program but I have no idea where to start.

UPDATE--

As per the comments I tried running spring version and now I get the error:

> Users/jgossling/Desktop/Spring Boot/spring-1.2.0.M2/bin/spring: line 83 : [Users/jgossling/Desktop/Spring: binary operator expected Error: could not find or load main class org.springframeowrk.boot.loader.JarLauncher

Comment: Its assuming you're trying to run something. The command you are looking for is `spring version`

Comment: thanks for the info so far.  I tried running spring version and now I get the error:  Users/jgossling/Desktop/Spring Boot/spring-1.2.0.M2/bin/spring: line 83 : [Users/jgossling/Desktop/Spring: binary operator expected  Error: could not find or load main class org.springframeowrk.boot.loader.JarLauncher

Comment: That seems... an ancient version of spring? Where did you install the CLI from?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.21.RELEASE/reference/html/getting-started-installing-spring-boot.html#getting-started-installation-instructions-for-java    maybe I accidentally grabbed an outdated version

Comment: Maybe try installing a current version and not a release candidate many years old? Current is 2.2.4 I think. CLI docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started-installing-the-cli

Comment: I believe so, old version of the CLI at least. The 1.5.x line of spring boot was EoL last august. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-cli.html is the latest docs

Comment: That is very strange I somehow was on an old installation tutorial page.  I will re install the newest version and update the question.

Comment: Could have just been the tutorial page. Spring publishes and keeps docs for each version, if its not linking to the reference of `current` it'll fall out of date.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like that `SET PATH=%PATH%;D:\Downloads\spring-2.5.0\bin` in cmd. Then, try to code `spring --version`. But it just works for this command line rather than forever. I make it but I don't really know why it works. Really hope this can help!